# Possible to have react + Django on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: django, reactjs, pythonanywhere

Is it possible to deploy react front end app and Django as back end app on pythonanyhere.com?

I have django API as back end and React as Front app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. React is just Javascript, so as long as you are serving your react code and loading it into your Django pages, it will just work.

Comment: How to install nodejs on pythonanywhere. I have complete front end in reactJs and using micro services django

Comment: node is already installed on PythonAnywhere, but you can use nvm to get a newer version of node if that is needed. see https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Node

Comment: just to clarify- you should use node to compile your react code to plain js and serve that js from your webapp- u should not be running a separate node server